# Counting Sum of Lines of all Files in Folder

Tags: windows

I am a programmer, and I am way too lazy to open up each of my project's files and count the lines, but I still want to know how many lines there are. Basically, I want to find the sum of all line breaks in a directory, which has sub-directories, and only if it has an extension of .html, .js, .css, or .php. Also also, I want it to work IN WINDOWS! And it should be free

Answer (score 3):

Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Ensure that packages `findutils`, `coreutils` and `dos2unix` are installed.

Run this command:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(html|js|css|php)' -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

The command should correctly process files with both Unix and DOS endlines. If a problem regarding endlines appears you can use the following variant with endlines translation:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(html|js|css|php)' -exec cat {} + | dos2unix | wc -l
```

The commands will count starting in the current directory. If you want to supply a different directory, put it instead of `.` right after `find`.

Comment: I don't want to install cygwin so I can count how many lines of code I have. Is there a more "lightweight" way to do this?

Comment: @Markasoftware: It is not necessary to install complete Cygwin. Probably `cygwin1.dll` and the tools you need will suffice though such manual installation will be more complicated. There is also [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) which does not use the Unix compatibility layer as Cygwin. Here is the [installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/) or [packages with individual binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/). The command sequence is intended for `bash` or any other shell similar to classic `sh`.